# Error console : document.getElementById().src = url is null

Tags: javascript

I try to pass an url parameter to wraper component in joomla 3

I call it via:

```
<body onload="getSparesUrl()">

<iframe >
    name="sparesframe"
    src ="<?php echo 'https://xxxxx.com/add_basket_ma.php?g7=xxxxxN&nr='.JRequest::getVar('urldyn'); ?>"
</iframe>
```

I don't understaand why i get an type error in console js : 
Maybye see someone what i missing with this function

> document.getElementById(getSparesUrl) is null

```
function getSparesUrl() {
        var url = 'https://xxxxxx.com/artikelsuche.php';
        var g7 = 'XXXXXXN'; 
        var query_string = location.search;
        if (query_string != '') {
            url = url + query_string + '&login=' + g7;
        } else {
            url = url + '?login=' + g7;
        }
    document.getElementById("sparesframe").src = url;
    };
```

Thank you any suggestion.

Comment: You are missing an element with `id='sparesframe'`

Comment: Hello Lixus thank for this answer, i get it solve with in jthe s file with : windows.onload = getSpareUrl;